# How to make bootable flash from ISO with DD?

Tags: boot, usb-flash-drive, iso-image, dd

I have downloaded [ALT Linux rescue ISO](https://en.altlinux.org/Rescue) and wrote it to my flash stick with

```
sudo dd if=regular-rescue-latest-x86_64.iso of=/dev/sda1
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't boot on my old computer. I tried USB-HDD, USB-CDROM, and also explicit entries in Harddrives section.

What this depends on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site says it's

> hybrid ISO image file suitable for both CD/DVD media and USB Flash pendrives.

But you need to `dd` it to a *whole* USB device, not a partition. `/dev/sda1` is a partition; `/dev/sda` is a whole device. You need `of=/dev/sda`.

Double check (e.g. with `lsblk`) that `sda` is the *right* device; don't destroy data on your HDD or something.